# Subscribing to an event that triggers a notification

Tags: java, android

I have a microcontroller (Particle Photon) that will publish an event to a cloud, and using their Android SDK I can 'subscribe' to that event. I want to have the event trigger a heads up notification on my phone, regardless of the current app I'm in.

How do apps like Facebook, Snapchat, etc. accomplish this? Are they really doing something like AlarmManager and pulling from their servers at a regular interval? I can't seem to find a background service solution that will persist through app closure, without a super annoying "foreground" service that invades my status bar and app shade.

IntentService, Service

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: You probably want to look at _Firebase Cloud Messaging_. (Note that Facebook specifically is so pervasive it may have its own equivalent messaging infrastructure, but you're not Facebook, so use someone else's.)

Comment: check this out. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
if your app is closed and you send notification from firebase it will create a notification in the notification panel. If your app is open you have to create custom notification using message received from Firebase.

Comment: @Michael I have tried using a Service class, but this gets killed off after a while, or if I close the main app. IntentService doesn't seem to be made for long-term running services. A foreground service _works_ but the permanent notification that I'm running a service that will notify you more just seems nasty and something that other apps don't seem to do. I will look into FCM, but at first glace I'm not sure it will work with the Photon unless I set up some custom server?